# Not able to upload file to sftp server using spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, sftp

hi i am getting the below exception when trying to upload csv file to SFTP server using spring integration, not able to figure out what is happening wrong , but on the server i can see file like **10132_1234.csv.writing** , but the writing opertaion never get complete ,whereas through winscp i am able to copy without any issue, please help to resolve this issue ,

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed
   to write to 'file-location/10132_1234.csv.writing' while uploading
   the file; nested exception is
   org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: failed to write file;
   nested exception is 3: Forbidden     at
   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.sendFileToRemoteDirectory(RemoteFileTemplate.java:560)
    at
   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.doSend(RemoteFileTemplate.java:337)
    ... 88 common frames omitted`enter code here`

   Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: failed to
   write file; nested exception is 3: Forbidden     at
   org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.write(SftpSession.java:177)
    at
   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$CachedSession.write(CachingSessionFactory.java:235)
    at
   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.doSend(RemoteFileTemplate.java:568)
    at
   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.sendFileToRemoteDirectory(RemoteFileTemplate.java:557)
    ... 89 common frames omitted

   Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException: Forbidden  at
   com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:594)   at
   com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:540)    at
   com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:492)    at
   org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.write(SftpSession.java:174)
    ... 92 common frames omitted
```

Here is my upload code :

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    factory.setHost(sftpHost);
    factory.setPort(sftpPort);
    factory.setUser(sftpUser);
    if (sftpPrivateKey != null) {
        factory.setPrivateKey(sftpPrivateKey);
        factory.setPrivateKeyPassphrase(sftpPrivateKeyPassphrase);
    } else {
        factory.setPassword(sftpPasword);
    }
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    logger.info("Entering into MessageHandler for uploading the file to SFTP server");
    SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
    handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(sftpRemoteDirectory));
    handler.setFileNameGenerator(message -> {
        if (message.getPayload() instanceof File) {
            return ((File) message.getPayload()).getName();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("File expected as payload.");
        }
    });
    return handler;
}

@MessagingGateway
public interface UploadGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "toSftpChannel")
    void upload(File file);

}
```

Comment: Forbidden likely means you may not have write access?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have permissions to write into remote files.

Comment: The `3` in `3: Forbidden` indicates `the authenticated user does not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation`. The code (3) and word `Forbidden` came from the server - look in the server logs.

Comment: It's quite likely you are using a wrong path. Try an absolute path.

Comment: Just some food for thought, I recently had to create an SFTP connector and I found the Spring-integration cumbersome so I used the underlying JSch library directly (which they use) and things went far more smoothly. I know this doesn't address your specific problem but it may save you time in the long run. In my case I also wanted flexibility in dynamically creating connections which was far easier using the library directly. I am sure everything can be done directly via the spring-integration but in my case wasn't worth the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether you have provided valid file path as the **destination**. It should be the exact file path on what it writes the upstream file content

```
springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.write(InputStream inputStream, String destination)
```